# Spring boot native build with multiple module

Tags: spring-boot, graalvm, graalvm-native-image

I'm now trying to build native executable by spring boot native build (GraalVM). [Spring Doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/native-image.html#native-image.developing-your-first-application.native-build-tools).

But the command `./mvnw native:compile` failed with

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.graalvm.buildtools:native-maven-plugin:0.9.22:compile (default-cli) on project myproject-parent: Execution of .jdks
> \graalvm-ce-17\bin\native-image.cmd @target\tmp\native-image-4847164668714484575.args returned non-zero result -> [Help 1]
>
> Error: Please specify class (or /) containing the main entry point method. (see --help)

I think it's because maven try build native for the parent module. But the parent module has no main class, it shouldn't build native image.

My project is multi-module. it looks like

- parent (inherit from spring-parent)

  - common
  - app-1
  - app-2

I want the native build only run for app-1 and app-2. How should I do?

Comment: from which location did you run that command. if you are in app-1 directory then run command will be: .././mvnw native:compile or if you are in parent directory then run command will be : ./mvnw app-1:native:compile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I find the correct way.

Spring doc says to use `native:compile`, but it will lead all module execute the goal. While we only want to run the goal on app modules.

So instead of run `native:compile`, we use normal `package`. And attach the `compile-no-fork` goal to `package` phase. Only enable the plugin in app modules.

Answer (score 0):

Sprint Native is new. Use JDK 21, GraalVM 21, Gradle plugin (alternative to Maven plugin) for more stable.